# How to find duplicate files i.e. with same name that exist in same parent directory?

Tags: windows, command-line, filesystems

I am doing clean up in my project. There are some modules in project which are being renamed or newly created or copied directly. In that process I have directly made copied renamed directory or created new directory. And now I want to delete old directory files. So I want to all files with their path which are having same name. (count > 2). There are 500+ of that type of files. That can be css, tpl, php or js files.

i.e.

1. Main/Games/troy.php
2. Main/Games/Child Games/troy.php
3. Main/Games/Sports/troy.php

If search is done on Main directory then search should return all 3 files and their paths.

So question is - How to find duplicate files i.e. with same name that exist in same parent directory?

I am using Windows SP2 and PHP. I need only search result no matter how it is provided. Anything like Command prompt, PHP logic, javascript logic, or any software giving results.

I have gone through some questions but they are not helpful to me.

1. [How to find duplicate files with same name but in different case that exist in same directory in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109056/how-to-find-duplicate-files-with-same-name-but-in-different-case-that-exist-in-s)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470258/how-do-i-find-all-files-with-the-same-name-in-all-subdirectories

Comment: why are the two linked ones not helpful to me and why do you have to do this with PHP? Why cant you just use the Windows Search Functions? Is that a programming question at all?

Comment: The easiest way to match them would be to compare each files MD5.

Comment: @Gordon: Both are for linux. And having somewhat different requirement. Is there any Windows Search Functions for doing same?

Comment: @CharliePrynn: I mean duplicate means files have same name only and no requirement of same content.

Comment: 2CharliePrynn files can be different, the only thing he asks for is for names to be equal. So md5 will not help

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/

Comment: @Gordon: In that resource, I need to specify file name. I don't want to specify file name whose duplicates I require. I will be giving input as directory name. And output will be list of duplicate files i.e have same name in that directory. And also I am using windows SP2 and not windows 7.

Comment: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html - unix commands on windows. just do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that recursively parses the specified directory tree and creates an associative array whose keys are the file names found in all subdirectories, and whose values are the corresponding paths. After running this function, all you have to do is iterate over the results and remove any file that has a higher appearance count than 1:

```
function scandir_recursive($dir, &$result = array()) {
    $dir = rtrim($dir, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

    foreach (scandir($dir) as $node) {
        if ($node !== '.' and $node !== '..') {
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $node)) {
                scandir_recursive($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $node, $result);
            } else {
                $result[$node][] = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $node;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(scandir_recursive(__DIR__));
```

Comment: Thanks.... it's returning all files with their existence in parent directory in array. Only require to check arrays count > 1..

Answer (score 0):

please install any IDE like Netbeans  or eclipse

there is an option called file search in that tab you have to specify the file name  and then search it will provide you all the file of same names

or you can go for normal file search in windows

i don't know is there any way to get files in all directories using php

Comment: I can find duplicates of any file are there. I want to get list of files that are duplicate i.e have same name by giving only directory name.

Comment: only one file be there in a folder of a single name

Comment: There can be many files in sub-folders or that folder. @Akhilraj

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a way to do this with Windows tools alone and/or want to do that with PHP, you can do

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('/path/you/want/to/search/in')
);

$allFiles = array();

foreach ($iterator as $fileObject) {
    $fileName = $fileObject->getFilename();
    if (!isset($files[$fileName])) {
        $files[$fileName] = array();
    }
    $files[$fileName][] = $fileObject->getPathname();
}
```

This will give you all files in and below that path keyed by their filename, e.g.

```
array(
    'foo.txt' => array('/path/to/foo.txt'),
    'bar.txt' => array(
        '/path/to/bar.txt',
        '/path/to/deeper/bar.txt',
    ),
);
```

To get the dupes you just filter out all those arrays with just one element in them:

```
$dupes = array_filter(
    $allFiles, 
    function(array $sameNamedFiles) {
        return count($sameNamedFiles) > 1;
    }
);
```

The result will then be something like

```
array(
    'bar.txt' => array(
        '/path/to/bar.txt',
        '/path/to/deeper/bar.txt',
    ),
);
```

If you want a "flat" array instead use

```
$dupes = array_reduce(
    $files, 
    function($dupes, array $sameNamedFiles) {
        if (count($sameNamedFiles) > 1) {
            $dupes = array_merge($dupes, $sameNamedFiles);
        }
        return $dupes;
    },
    array()
);
```

This will then result in something like

```
array(
    '/path/to/bar.txt',
    '/path/to/deeper/bar.txt',
)
```

Note: the above is untested but should point you in the general direction.